# How to Connect 2 Lists

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, parsing

I'm not sure wheter it's a simple thing or not.

I've an XML File structered like this:

```html
<DEFTABLE>
  <CUBE NAME="FristCube" />
      <OUT NAME="Line1" />
      <OUT NAME="Line2" />
      <IN NAME="LineX" />
      <IN NAME="LineY" />
  </CUBE>
  <CUBE NAME="SecondCube" />
      <OUT NAME="LineX" />
      <OUT NAME="LineY" />
      <IN NAME="Line1" />
      <IN NAME="Line2" />
  </CUBE>
</DEFTABLE>
```

Now I've created a List with all Cube Names, a List with all InLines and a List with all OutLines.
As you can see one Cube can have multiple InLines and OutLines - **how can i match these together?**

**I think i need a class "Cube" with all In- and Outlines included, but I've no clue how to realize that.**

I want to create 3D Objects of the CubeList (in Unity) and connect these Cubes with the proper Lines.

This is how i get the information into the List:

```js
private List<Cube> GetCubeList()
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load (@"Cube_List.xml");
    var cubes = (from c in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("CUBE")
        select new Cube
        {
            Cubename = (string)c.Attribute("NAME"),
            }).ToList();
    return cubes.ToList();

}

  ...

  private List<IN> GetINLines()
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load (@"Cube_List.xml");
    var inline = (from line in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("CUBE").Descendants("IN")
        select new InLine
        {
            Inline = (string)line.Attribute("NAME").Value,
        }).ToList();
    return inline().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Another approach is to create a class of `Line` and a class `Cube`. The class `Line` has two `Cube` Elements, the InCube and OutCube. Then you only need a `List<Line>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Cube`-class as foolows:

```
public class Cube
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem("In")
    public List<Element> In { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem("Out")
    public List<Element> Out { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set, }
}
```

Finally you´ll need your surrounding `DEFTABLE`-class:

```
[XmlRoot("DEFTABLE")]
public class DefTable
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Cube")]
    public List<Cube> Cubes { get; set; }
}
```

This should be easy to serialize/de-serialize to/from an Xml-file:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DefTable));
var instance = (DefTable) ser.DeSerialize(myFile);
```

This way is much easier than relying on Linq2Xml because you can directly use the class-structure you created before.

For more information and examples on serialization have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

EDIT: To get all `In`-lines from a `Cube` is quite easiy now:

```
var cube = instance.Cubes.Single(x => x.Name == "FristCube");
var inLines = cube.In;
```

Comment: This should work, but a DEFTABLE class with an "[XMLROOT]" attribute and a collection of Cubes in it would be better i think.

Comment: I had waited 3 minutes for you to add the missing parts, then added my comment:) Now the uppercase-lowercase thing may be a problem, but i agree with you; this solution is better than Linq2Xml

Comment: Heya, thanks for your solution! I've problems with your last "EDIT"-Part. "var cube = defTableInstance.Cubes.Single("FristCube");" , defTableInstance does not exist, i dont know what to insert there. Greetings

Comment: @V.Daymir I updated the answer, I ment the de-serialized instance of course.

Comment: @HimBromBeere ah cool thank you! Now I've got an error while compiling with the "Single": System.Collections.Generic.List does not have any defintion for "Single" and there are invalid arguments.

Comment: @V.Daymir Sorry, updated the statement. Ensure that you have a `using System.Linq` in your source-code file.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes I've `using System.Linq` included in my code. Now I've got following exception while compiling: `InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[Cube] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate, Fallback fallback)
System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[Cube] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate)` -- does that mean that cube.In is null? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @HimBromBeere Got it fixed, It was a Unity based error i did not really unterstand but i wrote the whole code snippet again (with MSDN) and now it works like a charm. Just one more question - how can get ALL Cubes with all their INs and OUTs? I can't figure it out.. Thanks a lot for your engagement!

Comment: @V.Daymir Simply call `instance.Cubes`. This will return all the cubes with all their in- and out-lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"Cube_List.xml");
List<XmlNode> allInOutNodes = new List<XmlNode>();

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("DEFTABLE/CUBE");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    allInOutNodes.AddRange(node.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a two pass algorithm.  First pass creates cubes, sides, and assign inputs to sides.  Second pass adds outputs to the sides.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication43
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            //pass one create cube and inputs
            foreach(XElement cube in  doc.Descendants("CUBE"))
            {
                Cube newCube = new Cube();
                Cube.cubes.Add(newCube);
                newCube.name = (string)cube.Attribute("NAME");
                newCube.sides = cube.Elements("IN").Select(y => new Side() {
                    name = (string)y.Attribute("NAME"),
                    _in = newCube
                }).ToList();
            }

            foreach (XElement xCube in doc.Descendants("CUBE"))
            {
                string outCubeName = (string)xCube.Attribute("NAME");
                Cube outCube = Cube.cubes.Where(x => x.name == outCubeName).FirstOrDefault();

                foreach(XElement _out in xCube.Elements("OUT"))
                {
                    string sideName = (string)_out.Attribute("NAME");
                    Boolean found = false;
                    foreach (Cube inCube in Cube.cubes)
                    {
                        foreach (Side side in inCube.sides)
                        {
                            if (side.name == sideName)
                            {
                                side._out = outCube;
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (found == true) break;
                    }
                }
            }



        }
    }
    public class Cube
    {
        public static List<Cube> cubes = new List<Cube>();

        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Side> sides { get; set; }

    }
    public class Side
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Cube _in { get; set; }
        public Cube _out { get; set; }
    }
}
```